# how to stop ajax calls if there's no changes made

Tags: forms, jquery

Imagine the first time, the data doesn't matched and ajax has returned the request then sending an error message to the form, after that how do i stop ajax call if there's no changes made on the form/input?

```
$("input[name=signup]").click(function(event) {

if ($(this).attr('type') == "submit" && $(this).attr('name') == "signup") {

        formValidate = function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:   "/ajax/req-signup.aspx",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { ... },
                success: function(response) { ... }
            });
        }
        formValidate();
    }
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `there's no changes made` don't get it.

Comment: This means the user have not changed anything in the inputs value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a global variable

```
var allowAjax = true;
```

set it to false when validation fails:

```
allowAjax = false;
```

set to true when changing something in the form

```
$("input").change(function () {
    allowAjax = true;
});
```

and check it's status when making the ajax call:

```
if ($(this).attr('type') == "submit" 
   && $(this).attr('name') == "signup" 
   && allowAjax ) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you can disable the submit button when the validation fails and enable it on change.

```
$(":submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

If you don't mind using a plugin, check out [jQuery disabler widget](http://www.dougestep.com/dme/jquery-disabler-widget), you might find it easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the click event only when something changes - then unbind it when the click event is fired (thus negating the need for a globally available variable):

```
/* whenever an input changes on your form, bind click event */
$("SELECT INPUTS HERE").change(function (){
    /* unbind first to ensure the click event won't be registered/triggered multiple times */
    $("input[name=signup]").unbind("click").click(doSignup);
});

function doSignup(e){
    if ($(this).attr("type") == "submit" && $(this).attr("name") == "signup"){
        /* a successful click has happened - unbind click */
        $("input[name=signup]").unbind("click");

        /* do ajax call */
        $.ajax({
            url:   "/ajax/req-signup.aspx",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { ... },
            success: function(response) { ... }
        });
    };

    e.preventDefault();
};
```

From a UX perspective you could enhance this in a few ways.

1. Also "disable" the button whenever you unbind the click, or
   otherwise indicate to the user that the button is not currently in a
   clickable state.
2. Instead of unbinding on the click, consider
   unbinding conditionally. Like, unbind on success but don't unbind on
   error so they can try again. Also, if you're doing input validation,
   maybe unbind when the user's input isn't valid. Et cetera.

Hope that helps!